# ios::base:precision & setprecision

Tags: c++

What is the difference between ios::base:precision & setprecision 
Given in the following links?
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/

Comment: `setprecision` is a stream manipulator so you can use it in this form: `cout << setprecision(n)`. `precision` is just a member function that does the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

The difference it to do with the usage.
The first (setter) is a member function, so gets called like this:

```
std::cout.precision(10);
```

The second isn't a member function so is called different.

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(10);
```

The 2nd link explicitly says

"Behaves as if member precision were called with n as argument on the stream on which it is inserted/extracted as a manipulator "

Comment: than it means  quoted in the link 
"For the default locale:
    Using the default floating-point notation, the precision field specifies the maximum number of meaningful digits to display in total counting both those before and those after the decimal point. Notice that it is not a minimum, and therefore it does not pad the displayed number with trailing zeros if the number can be displayed with less digits than the precision.."

apples to setprecision

Answer (score 0):

Citing your second link:

> Behaves as if member `precision` were called with n as argument on the
>   stream on which it is inserted/extracted as a manipulator (it can be
>   inserted/extracted on input streams or output streams).

Thus, there's no difference.

Comment: than it means quoted in the link "For the default locale: Using the default floating-point notation, the precision field specifies the maximum number of meaningful digits to display in total counting both those before and those after the decimal point. Notice that it is not a minimum, and therefore it does not pad the displayed number with trailing zeros if the number can be displayed with less digits than the precision.." apples to setprecision

Comment: I don't understand your question. Rephrase and add to your original question, please.

Comment: I am writing the code Int main(){ int 155.234; cout<<setprecision(2);}
Its giving me outoput 1.5e+002

Comment: than it means quoted in the link "For the default locale: Using the default floating-point notation, the precision field specifies the maximum number of meaningful digits to display in total counting both those before and those after the decimal point. Notice that it is not a minimum, and therefore it does not pad the displayed number with trailing zeros if the number can be displayed with less digits than the precision.." apples to setprecision

Comment: Otherwise its answer should be 1.55

Comment: @Rizvi You need to use `std::fixed`: `cout << std::fixed << setprecision(2) << 155.234;`